# Where is Gronwalls Lemma applied in the Picard-Lindelof Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

So I'm doing a project on this theorem for my analysis class, and when I look at the "proof sketch" on wikipedia, it says: "An application of Grönwall's lemma to |φ(t) − ψ(t)|, where φ and ψ are two solutions, shows that φ(t) = ψ(t), thus proving the global uniqueness."

But, when I look at the detailed proof I see no application of Grönwall's lemma. Is there a mistake? What am I missing? Thanks!

[Here's the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Comment: Indeed, Gronwall's lemma is not needed for the proof of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem (which is of local nature). Better to look for proof sketches in books anyways. What happens is that for globally Lipschitz functions one can additionally show (independently of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem) that the solution is global and (thus) unique globally. And for that one can (for example) use Gronwall's lemma.

Comment: The usual proof is via the Banach fixed-point theorem, which already contains uniqueness in its statement. You could alternatively first cite Cauchy-Peano for the existence and then use Grönwall for the uniqueness.

Comment: So shouldn't the statement "An application of Grönwall's lemma to |φ(t) − ψ(t)|, where φ and ψ are two solutions, shows that φ(t) = ψ(t), thus proving the global uniqueness." not be in the proof sketch?